# Bootstrap spans within spans

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working with Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.5.

Well basically, my structure is that I have a fixed sidebar on the left (span4) and a main content area on the right (span8, #main)

Within #main I have placed a .hero-unit and after that a row that should contain two columns, both spam4.

Here is a shortened version of my code:

...

```
  <div class="span8 offset4" id="main">
            <div class="hero-unit">
             ....
            </div>

            <div class="span4" id="main-left">
                <article>
                    <h3>Head here</h3>
                    <p>Some Text here</p>
                </article>
            </div>

            <div class="span4" id="main-right">
                <article>
                    <h3>Head here</h3>
                    <p> Some Text Here</p>
                </article>
            </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem now is that the #main-left and #main-right is now placed outside the container. 
[image]

What seems to be the problem with my code?

Comment: Looks like your "head here" blocks are outside the `.span8` container. If you could post a fiddle that'd be helpful.

Comment: You need to use rows when nesting in BS 2.3 - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this? http://jsfiddle.net/SXVHm/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minus your ID's and any custom classes, this should work for you:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="span4">
           <p class="text-center"><img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></p>
           <p>Look at this stuff, isn't it neat wouldn't you think my collection complete. Wouldn't you think Im a girl a girl who has everything.</p>
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="span8">
           <div class="hero-unit">
               <h1>Hero Unit</h1>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="span4">
                   <h3>Head here</h3>
                   <p>I've heard it said, that people come into our life...</p>
               </div>
               <div class="span4">
                   <h3>Head here</h3>
                   <p>Like a comet pulled from orbit as it passes the sun...</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[**View Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SXVHm/4/)

Answer (score 0):

See comments regarding nesting columns and rows. But try this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
    The sidebar content
  </div>
  <div class="span8" id="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hero-unit">
        ....
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4" id="main-left">
        <article>
          <h3>Head here</h3>
          <p>Some Text here</p>
        </article>
      </div>

      <div class="span4" id="main-right">
        <article>
          <h3>Head here</h3>
          <p> Some Text Here</p>
        </article>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code isn't right either unfortunately. Notice the horizontal scrollbar: thehttp://jsfiddle.net/SXVHm/2/

Comment: Row-fluid fixes that. See http://jsfiddle.net/SXVHm/3/ (updated answer to this fiddle)

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't have to use `.row-fluid` here, and `.row-fluid` doesn't make it responsive out of the gate. It makes the container and contents % based. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SXVHm/4/) isn't using `.row-fluid` and it's still responsive. `.row-fluid` is based of %'s, not fixed width numbers. `.row` and corresponding `.spanX` classes are based off fixed width numbers, per BS 2.3.x docs. To make your site responsive, you need to include the responsive stylesheet after the core.

Comment: My apologies, there's some confusion. I wasn't intending to imply row-fluid automatically made it responsive, just that applying them fixed the scroll bar issue in your /2/ fiddle. I see now that applying row-fluid, although fixes it, isn't the only fix. The span8 can also be removed from class="span8 hero-unit" to remove the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: You got it! Just wanted to make you aware that `.hero-unit` itself is a block element, so it doesn't "need" a `.spanX` class to fill the container.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you..

```
<div class="span8 offset4" id="main">       
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="hero-unit"> 
                .... 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6" id="main-left">
            <article>
                <h3>Head here</h3>
                <p>Some Text here</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="span6" id="main-right">
            <article>
                <h3>Head here</h3>
                <p> Some Text Here</p>
            </article>
        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>
```